# Sorting methods (by number of arguments) using JetBrains Rider File Layout

Tags: unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm using Unity/C# and I try to setup Rider File Layout XML to format code in specific way.

- **What I want** - is to put methods with certain names (e.g. `Awake()`, `Start()`, `Update()` etc.) in front of other methods.
- **The important part** is that I want to move ***only methods without arguments***.

Sorting by name partially works, but it also changes order of methods with parameters (e.g. `Update(float dt)`).

Is there any way to filter methods with and without parameters using File Layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible, probably you have to write your own R# plugin for this

Comment: Is it actually possible to create plugin that changes File Layout reordering logic?

Comment: Not the existing Rider logic, but you could implement your very own logic